# Convert factor type time into number of minutes

Tags: r, time

There is a column in my dataset that contains time in the format `00:20:10`. I have two questions. First, when I import it into R using `read.xlsx2()`, this column is converted to factor type. How can I convert it to time type?
Second, I want to calculate each person's total time in number of minutes.

```
ID      Time
 1  00:10:00
 1  00:21:30
 2  00:30:10
 2  00:04:10
```

The output I want is:

```
ID Total.time
 1       31.5
 2       34.3
```

I haven't dealt with time issue before, and I hope someone would recommend some packages as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `times()` from the *chron* package to convert the `Time` column to "times" class. Then `aggregate()` to sum the times, grouped by the `ID` column.  This first block will give us actual times in the result.

```
library(chron)

df$Time <- times(df$Time)
aggregate(list(Total.Time = df$Time), df[1], sum)
#   ID Total.Time
# 1  1   00:31:30
# 2  2   00:34:20
```

For decimal output, we can employ `minutes()` and `seconds()`, also from *chron*.

```
aggregate(list(Total.Time = df$Time), df[1], function(x) {
    minutes(s <- sum(x)) + (seconds(s) / 60)
})
#   ID Total.Time
# 1  1   31.50000
# 2  2   34.33333
```

Furthermore, we can also use *data.table* for improved efficiency.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Total.Time = minutes(s <- sum(Time)) + (seconds(s) / 60)), by = ID]
#    ID Total.Time
# 1:  1   31.50000
# 2:  2   34.33333
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Time = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("00:04:10", "00:10:00", "00:21:30", "00:30:10"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Got it!@Richard

Comment: What if my time is like "112:23:09", the hour is more than 24 hours. When I use the times ( ), I got warning message: "time out of day entry". So should I convert them into data, then minutes.